# Closing dialog button using a button

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a dialog box to allow the user to choose male or female. I can close it by clicking off it, but need to know how to close it when the mConfirm button is clicked.

```js
    public String getRadioValue() {
        final String[] mRadioString = {"Male"};

        final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this);
        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_input, null);
        mBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        final RadioButton mMaleRadio = (RadioButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.radMale);
        final RadioButton mFemaleRadio = (RadioButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.radFemale);
        final RadioGroup mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) mView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        Button mConfirm = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);

        mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mMaleRadio.isChecked()) {
                    mRadioString[0] = "Male";
                } else {
                    mRadioString[0] = "Female";
                }
                
            }
        });

        mBuilder.setView(mView);
        AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();

        return mRadioString[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`dialog.dismiss()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss()) in your `ClickListener`.

```
    final String[] mRadioString = {"Male"};

    final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this);
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_input, null);
    mBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    final RadioButton mMaleRadio = (RadioButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.radMale);
    final RadioButton mFemaleRadio = (RadioButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.radFemale);
    final RadioGroup mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) mView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    Button mConfirm = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);


    mBuilder.setView(mView);
    final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

    mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mMaleRadio.isChecked()) {
                mRadioString[0] = "Male";
            } else {
                mRadioString[0] = "Female";
            }
            dialog.dismiss();                
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to work, could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: You have some other issues with synchronicity, but I've edited a version of your code in my answer to show at least how to dismiss the dialog in the click listener.